# Google column charts X-axis label different from value

Tags: google-visualization

I'd like to create column chart with X axis numeric values 1, 2, 3, 4 ... N and Y value of course different on every column. 
I can't find out how to change labels on X line under bars, to string. For example - 1 could be marked as Elephant, 2 as Horse etc.

I could use string as X values, but then there is no way to get zoom working. At least, I didn't find any way to get it working.

simple example with strings, I'd like to achieve same appearance as this one, but with numeric values on X axis.

```
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'animal');
  data.addColumn('number', 'count');

  data.addRows([
    ['Elephant', 5],
    ['Horse', 2],
    ['Dog', 7],
    ['Cat', 4],
  ]);

  var options = {
  explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
},

    title: 'Testing',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Animal',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'number'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Chart should look like this, but with working zoom:
[Chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFwSI.png)

Answer (score 1):

to use string labels on a [continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous) axis,
you will need to provide your own `ticks`

using object notation, provide the value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`)

```
{v: 1, f: 'Elephant'}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'animal');
  data.addColumn('number', 'count');
  data.addRows([
    [1, 5],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 7],
    [4, 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    explorer: {
      axis: 'horizontal'
    },
    title: 'Testing',
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 1, f: 'Elephant'},
        {v: 2, f: 'Horse'},
        {v: 3, f: 'Dog'},
        {v: 4, f: 'Cat'}
      ],
      title: 'Animal',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'number'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```